# Receive events in an event-loop, single-threaded

Tags: event-programming

Let's say I have a program which consists of a main event loop. The event loop should check for tasks and if one exists, it is to be processed. The user interface consists of a GUI with buttons, for each of which can be defined a callback function when it is pressed.

Using multiple threads, I can simply execute the event loop in a separate thread. When a button is pressed, I feed a task into a queue which is shared by the UI and the event thread. The event thread then consumes and executes the task.

My question is how this behaviour is realized in a single threaded application or a language that does not support multithreading. My idea is to poll for user interaction, but how does this work in said GUI where a button press can only be registered by the invocation of a specified callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS creates events and feeds it into the OS-supplied Event queue which the application polls in the event loop.

In Windows that is with [`GetMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends.

Windowing frameworks (java's swing, Qt etc.) will implement this loop for you and allow you to insert your own custom events.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix several tasks in a single threaded loop, e.g. by using idle functions (as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836758/841108)).

So with a GUI event loop, when some external event happens (e.g. the user presses a button), the callback could add an idle function into the loop.

Then it is important that the idle function gives back the control to the event loop quite quickly (typically, in a few milliseconds). It could add itself again to the loop to continue some processing.

Of course, the concept of [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) is relevant, and you can see an idle-function re-adding itself as some hand-written [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28877678/841108) for more references.